# how to apply class in DOM using value returned from a function in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have my DOM element as :

```
<i id= class="icon clr-org fleft ion-bookmark" ng-class="{business.class : setFavouriteBusinessIcon(business.ID, $index)}"></i>
```

now I want to apply `business.class` which is a variable in my scope as the element's class whenever `setFavouriteBusinessIcon(business.ID, $index)` returns true.

but the current ng-class condition is not working.

Comment: class="{{className}}" this works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by having single quotes and `{{...}}` around it. Like this:

```
<i ng-class="{'{{business.class}}' : setFavouriteBusinessIcon(business.ID, $index)}"></i>
```

Here's a working example: (notice that `world` class has been applied and so is its CSS)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'world';
});
```

```css
.world {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p ng-class="{'{{name}}': true}">Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>

</html>
```